# GPL-3.0 library in MIT project

Tags: licensing, gpl, mit, website

I'm working on a project comprised of a small HTML page and a JavaScript script.

From the HTML page I include a library which is licensed under the GNU General Public License v3.0, and from my script I invoke some of its functions.

I would like to release the HTML page and the script file under the MIT License, but I'm not sure... Is it allowed?

I know MIT and GPL-3.0 code can be mixed, but in this case the GPL-3.0 code is a dependency of the would-be-MIT code.

I think I would be allowed to simply publish a code repository with my MIT code (without a copy of the GPL-3.0 library), and to publish the web page with a link to both my repository and the original repository of the library. Would I be correct? Would I also be required to host a copy of the source code of the library?

Thanks!

Comment: Who is owning the copyright on the code? If you own it alone, you could dual license it. In principle, you need agreement of other contributors to change licenses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot **distribute** GPL-covered code in an MIT-licensed project. You have to use GPL (or a compatible license) for the project as a whole, if you include GPL-covered libraries.

I can also be argued that running a website is distributing the code, so even combining it on the front-end of a running web server is at least very fishy and must not be done; GPL very likely was chosen for that very reason.

Comment: Running software on a server is absolutely not distribution/conveyance in the sense of the GPL. But including the software in the frontend absolutely is, and therefore implies responsibilities like providing a copy of the license and the corresponding source code to recipients (visitors of the website).

Comment: @amon yes, thanks. When saying 'webserver' I meant to refer to the front-end part which is visible to outside users. I amended my text to reflect that.

Comment: Your first paragraph is contradictory. The MIT license is compatible with the GPL, so you are both saying that you can and cannot use the MIT license.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I don't follow your argument. I say GPL in MIT: bad. (but MIT in GPL ok)

Comment: @planetmaker, and then you go on to say "Use GPL (or a compatible license)", but MIT falls under the parenthetical remark. What might be better o say is that the project as a whole needs to be distributed under the GPL (due to the GPL library), but all individual files, including those written by the OP, only need to be under a GPL-compatible license, for which the MIT qualifies as well.

Comment: While I still fail to see the argument I don't mind to make it clearer. Better now?

Comment: I have made a small edit, as what you wrote didn't quite say what I think you meant. ("whole project" means "every single line in the project", whereas "project as a whole" means "looking at the project as a single entity").

Comment: I was reluctant to just release my code as GPL-3.0 because I don't understand all the implications, but if this is my only option, so be it. Thank you very much for helping me!